# C#.NET - Signing HTTP POST message with HMAC-SHA512 produces inconsistent result in some systems

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest, hmac

I'm building a program that interacts with a cryptocurrency exchange's API to place buy/sell order, etc.

In order to use the exchange's private API methods, I have to include a sign in the http header, which is the POST message body, encrypted with HMACSHA512 by using a secret key.

The code below works totally fine in my system, but some of my users reported that the server always returns a signing error when they try to use some of the private API methods.

I've tried to reproduce the bug in several system setups, but to no avail.

I'm wondering if any part of the code below is prone to inconsistency when being used in different system setups.

```
    public string SendQuery(string apiKey, string secretKey, string method, string[] param, string url)
    {
        // nonce
        string nonceStr = Utility.CurrentTimeMillis().ToString() + "0000000000";

        // generate the POST message
        string postString = "method=" + method + "&nonce=" + nonceStr;
        if (param != null) 
        {
            foreach (string item in param) postString += "&" + item;
        }            
        byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postString);

        // sign POST message
        HMACSHA512 hMACSHA512 = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));
        byte[] sign = hMACSHA512.ComputeHash(postData);
        string signString = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < sign.Length; i++)
        {
            signString += sign[i].ToString("X2");
        }
        signString = signString.ToLower();   //　must use lower case

        // generate headers
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("Key", apiKey);
        request.Headers.Add("Sign", signString);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = 5000;

        string message = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (Stream st = request.GetRequestStream())
                st.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);

            Stream responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            string line = "";

            while (line != null)
            {
                line = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (line != null) message += line;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return message;
    }
```

Comment: The code won't work if the secret key has non-ASCII characters as these will be converted to question marks as the encoding's replacement character. Basically this will routinely affect all non-English speakers. You should research which encoding the server used to calculate the HMACs, but I guess they used UTF8.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, in my case the server always uses ASCII character (hexadecimals) for the secret keys.

Answer (score 2):

So answering my own question,

Turns out the problem doesn't lie within my SendQuery method, but a function that calls it uses Double.ToString("F8") to produce a parameter value, which results in varying decimal separator character depending on the local formatting.

For example:

```
double val = 1000.5;

string str = val.ToString("F8");
```

Depending on the formatting will produces either
"1000.50000000" or 
"1000,50000000".

So you have to provide the IFormatProvider argument when using the Double.ToString method,
or just use a dirty-but-works-like-a-charm trick like:

```
ToString("F8").Replace(",", ".");
```